# Delphi - Split string by line break

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, line-breaks, split

Note: I am using Delphi 7.

Is there a way to split a string by a line break?

I would like something like the following:

```
procedure Split
   (const Delimiter: Char;
    Input: string;
    const Strings: TStrings) ;
begin
   Assert(Assigned(Strings)) ;
   Strings.Clear;
   Strings.Delimiter := Delimiter;
   Strings.DelimitedText := Input;
end;

var
  xMSG:String;
  xStr:String;
  xStrList:TStrings;
  xLineBreak:String;
  xHello:String;
  xWorld:String;
begin
  xLineBreak := AnsiString(#13#10);
  xMSG := 'Hello ' + xLineBreak + 'World';
  xStrList := TStringList.Create;
  Split(xLineBreak,AnsiString(xMSG),xStrList);
  xHello := xStrList[0];
  xWorld := xStrList[1];
  MessageBox(0,PAnsiChar(xHello + xWorld),'Test',0);
end.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is what the `Text` property does. Quote from the help (Text property (TStrings)):

> Lists the strings in the TStrings object as a single string with the
>   individual strings delimited by carriage returns and line feeds.

Since it would be a one liner, you don't need an additional utility procedure.

```
var
  xMSG:String;
//  xStr:String;
  xStrList:TStrings;
//  xLineBreak:String;
  xHello:String;
  xWorld:String;
begin
//  xLineBreak := AnsiString(#13#10);     // you don't need this, there's sLineBreak
  xMSG := 'Hello ' + sLineBreak + 'World';
  xStrList := TStringList.Create;

//  Split(xLineBreak,AnsiString(xMSG),xStrList);  
  xStrList.Text := xMSG;  // <--

  xHello := xStrList[0];
  xWorld := xStrList[1];
  xStrList.Free;
  MessageBox(0,PAnsiChar(xHello + xWorld),'Test',0);
end;
```